# Setting up Azure CDN

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

We have a web app that runs on Azure App Service and it has its own domain i.e. myapp.com

We now want to host all static files such as images, css and js files through Azure CDN to improve responsiveness of the app. We'll be storing all these files in our Azure storage and we've created two containers i.e. "images" and "files" containers. We also want to use our own custom domain and I'd like the URLs to be:

https://cdn.myapp.com/images for images and https://cdn.myapp.com/files for all other files.

I'm a bit confused about how to map storage containers to endpoints. When I go to the portal and select "Storage" as origin type, I see the storage account but that doesn't let me point to a particular container.

How do I map specific containers to end points?

"images" container should be available through https://cdn.myapp.com/images
"files" container should be available through https://cdn.myapp.com/files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to map a container to the CDN, you map the blob endpoint to the CDN

Let's say your blob endpoint is:
[mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net](http://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net)

The origin url should just be:
[mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net](http://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net)

Your static fill will be accessible by:
[mycdn.azureedge.net/images/image1.jpg](http://mycdn.azureedge.net/images/image1.jpg)
[mycdn.azureedge.net/files/text.txt](http://mycdn.azureedge.net/files/text.txt)

Then you can add custom domain "cdn.myapp.com" to "mycdn.azureedge.net", after that your images and files will be available through [cdn.myapp.com/images/image1.jpg](http://cdn.myapp.com/images/image1.jpg)
[cdn.myapp.com/files/text.txt](http://cdn.myapp.com/files/text.txt)

Comment: Thank you Kuangwei. Looks like Microsoft's current approach will CDN all the containers under a storage account if it's linked to a CDN profile. This means I need to create a whole new storage account for CDN because I have other containers under the existing one and I do NOT want those containers to be CDN'ed! I thought Microsoft's approach would be much more granular.

Comment: If your container is not public, then files in there will not be CDN'ed

Comment: Got it! Very useful. Thank you!